# Display Custom URL path for better SEO - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been looking around for some way to tweak routes.rb in a way that instead of routing page url's to numbers (ids) that may be not very good to page SEO, I would prefer to have event names on the tittle. Example:

At the moment I have this:

```
example.com/events/666
```

I should have this:

```
example.com/events/better-page-url-seo
```

The "better page url seo" is the attribute name associated with id "666".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the gem `friendly_id`. for more info look [here](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)